# Issue with scraping dynamic content with Selenium & BeautifulSoup

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list of links that I would like to open and then extract some data from that links. The links feature company profiles and all refer to the same site. The html of each site/ company profile has the same structure when inspected under the developer tools. For some reason my code cannot properly fetch the data from all profiles. Attached you find the code that I use. Any suggestions how to improve my code to achieve the goal?

````
# Set up Chrome options and service
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'  # or 'eager'
service = Service("/usr/bin/chromedriver")  # Specify the path to the ChromeDriver executable

# Common data object to store extracted information
all_data = []
failed_urls = []

# Function to fetch and parse content from a URL with Selenium
def fetch_and_parse_content_selenium(url):
    try:
        # Initialize Chrome WebDriver
        with webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options) as driver:
            # Navigate to the URL
            driver.get(url)
            time.sleep(2)  # Add a delay to ensure the page loads

            # Your specific parsing logic using BeautifulSoup and CSS selectors
            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

            # Your specific parsing logic using BeautifulSoup and CSS selectors
            company_name2 = soup.select_one('h1.font-extralight').text.strip() if soup.select_one('h1.font-extralight') else None
            batch = soup.select_one('div.flex.flex-row.items-center span').text.strip() if soup.select_one('div.flex.flex-row.items-center span') else None
            acquisition = soup.select_one('div.flex.flex-row.items-center.justify-between span').text.strip() if soup.select_one('div.flex.flex-row.items-center.justify-between span') else None
            url = soup.select_one('div.inline-block.group-hover\:underline a').get('href').strip() if soup.select_one('div.inline-block.group-hover\:underline a') else None
            title = soup.select_one('.prose .text-xl').text.strip() if soup.select_one('.prose .text-xl') else None
            description = soup.select_one('p.whitespace-pre-line').text.strip() if soup.select_one('p.whitespace-pre-line') else None
            founded_date_span = soup.select_one('div.flex.flex-row.justify-between span:contains("Founded:") + span')
            founded_date = founded_date_span.text.strip() if founded_date_span else None
            team_size_span = soup.select_one('div.flex.flex-row.justify-between span:contains("Team Size:") + span')
            team_size = team_size_span.text.strip() if team_size_span else None
            location_span = soup.select_one('div.flex.flex-row.justify-between span:contains("Location:") + span')
            location = location_span.text.strip() if location_span else None
            founders_count = len(soup.find_all('div', class_='shrink-0 space-y-1.5 rounded-md border-[1px] border-[#999] bg-[#FDFDF7] p-6 sm:w-[300px]'))

            # Return the extracted information
            return {
                'company_name2': company_name2,
                'batch': batch,
                'acquisition': acquisition,
                'url': url,
                'title': title,
                'description': description,
                'founded_date': founded_date,
                'team_size': team_size,
                'location': location,
                'founders_count': founders_count
            }

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching/parsing content from {url} with Selenium: {e}")
        failed_urls.append(url)
        return None

# Loop through the URLs in the DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    url = row['href']

    # Fetch and parse content with Selenium
    data = fetch_and_parse_content_selenium(url)

    if data:
        # Append extracted information to the common data object
        all_data.append(data)

# Convert the list of results into a DataFrame
result_df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)

# Concatenate the original DataFrame with the new DataFrame containing extracted information
df = pd.concat([df, result_df], axis=1)

# Display the updated DataFrame
print(df)

# Output the list of URLs that failed to parse
print("Failed URLs:")
for failed_url in failed_urls:
    print(failed_url)```
````

Comment: Perhaps there is an event handler attached to each row which appends some kind of route or query string parameter to the url when you click it? Have you tried opening the page in your browser and clicking a row's profile link and inspect your network tab? Maybe they have a profile id or something as a data attribute on the link or container.

Comment: Without further information, it is difficult to understand what the cause might be. What is the difference between the respective pages and what does not all information mean? maybe they are not available on the pages, then they cannot be extracted. what about two urls, one that works and one that does not?

Comment: Ok maybe to give you some more information. I already tested links where the information was not extracted. Typically for those sites all information is NaN. When I took the script to extract only the information for this individual URL information extraction somehow worked. So my suscpicion is that it has to do with the webdriver or dynamic web content. Btw. is it allowed to share one of the profiles that I scrape?

Comment: @Ryan Wilson I observed that under Network/ XHR an Id was added. Was that the question? Sorry I am not familiar with the workings of event handlers

Comment: In my opinion it is okay, because it would be a debug detail to reproduce the behaviour. However I would guess that the page needs some more time to render in specific cases so you may have to wait until all elements ar present.

Comment: @Nick Yes that was what I was describing above. They are passing along some id property in the url. As **HedgeHog** pointed out, it may be that you aren't waiting for all the rows to load before executing your page script. Might be good to look for something that loads at the end of the page to use a Selenium Wait

Comment: @HedgeHog Ok so this means you would suggest to experiment with increasing time.sleep() or put a WebDriverWait?

Comment: @Nick Yes, without any additional knowledge but try `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'YOUR ELEMENT SELECTOR')))` over  `time.sleep()`

Comment: Ok I just wonder which element I put under 'YOUR ELEMENT SELECTOR'. Probably some element at the end of the page?

Comment: For some reason WebDriverWait does not work. I still cannot extract information from some URLs despite them having the same html structure as the other URLs

Comment: ok another thing I noticed. When I run the script multiple times sometimes it is able to fetch data and sometimes not.

Comment: As mentioned, without any further details exception / url we just can guess, what is wrong, because behaviour is not reproduceable.